# Use Settings of Used Middleware

Tags: node.js, recursion, express, middleware

By "setting" I mean "something that is set", similar to "setters" in Java & other OO languages, not Express's "application settings". Is there a way to access and ideally use "settings" set inside middleware `use()`d by the app? In particular, some middleware is a full Express app, like `vhost` and the new `Router` middleware that comes with Express 4.x. If you do most of your routing in a virtual host and want to access some route param from the main app, that could be a problem. This is especially true if you have several layers, like I'm having, and it would be inconvenient to `export` the setting all the way out to the main app.

So is there a way to access these settings from the main app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In particular, some middleware is a full Express app

Express 4.x has a great new feature to get around this problem.  You can now use `express.Router` directly.  In cases where you used to use an entire routing path by using a second sub-Express object as middleware, now you can just use Router.

For anything else, I usually add properties to the request object, namespaced by the name of my app.

```
function (req, res, next) {
  req.myApp = req.myApp || {};
  req.myApp.someData='whatever';
  next();
}
```

The next middleware in the line will have access to this variable.  I use this to track unique connection IDs, assigned by the first piece of middleware and subsequently used by others.

Comment: Yes, but the variables I'm setting are explicitly part of the middleware, not the outer Express app. And I'm using `vhost` to do virtual hosting, which I don't believe is possible to do with a `Router`.

Comment: @trysis That's why I suggested attaching data to requests.  If that doesn't apply to your situation, please expound on your question as I'm not understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I'll have to try it in my app. I'm sure there are other reasons for what I'm asking, but I can't think of any off the top of my head :).

Comment: how do you manage virtual hosts? This is what has been giving me the most pain, especially since I used to use Apache & they were relatively easier there. Otherwise, again, great approach.

Comment: @trysis Personally, I manage virtual host routing in Nginx, but if you need virtual hosts inside your application than it is appropriate to do this with middleware.  I don't really follow what problem you're having with virtual hosts.  Like I said earlier, if you have some upstream middleware that needs to pass data downstream, you can attach it to the request object before calling `next()`.

Comment: I think I can solve it. I'm doing logic with subdomains (big headache), and I thought I'd have to do this logic before I do the rest of the app, but now I'm thinking I can redirect afterwards instead.

Comment: @trysis I would suggest posting a new question fully describing your situation, and asking for a way to refactor.